# Python Invalid Syntax with my “if not in and statement”

Tags: python

I use the code as follows:

However, I got the following error:

> File “”, line 5 if student not in unique_engagement_students and
>   enrollment[‘join_date’] ！= enrollment[‘cancel_date’]: ^ SyntaxError:
>   invalid syntax

Comment: if 'student' not in unique_engagement_students, student is a parsed as a variable not a string

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show your coding efforts?

Answer (score 2):

`!=` must be written as a unit - `! =` is a SyntaxError.